# drawing a tree - android

Tags: android, tree

I've been trying to create something like this with android , but I couldn't make it : 
[image]

The tree shape is already defined ,and the tree branches should be clickable , so that it would be possible to change the style of the lines ( bold / dotted / normal ) .

I need to know if there is a way to draw a tree structure with android

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: don't expect us to write all the code for you, try to write it by yourself and if you find some problem post it here

Comment: I dind't expect that xD , I just need to know if there is a way to draw a tree structure with android

Comment: You can draw anything from a pixel to a closed polygon (and circles, ovals, rectangles, lines, text).  Of course it's possible.

Comment: thanks @Simon for your answer , can you give me an example/tutorial of something like a tree ?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want to `implement` a `treeView` in `android`.

I've implemented it with `Custom ListView`, here's a link where I've posted example of my `implementation`:

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20518117/2219052

Hope it helps.