# Tree List View In Android

Tags: android, android-listview, tree

I am trying to do a tree list in android using [this project library](http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/).

First: I cannot import it in Eclipse. I am getting the following error:

```
[2014-01-15 14:58:18 - tree-view-list-android] Android requires compiler compliance level 5.0 or 6.0. Found '1.7' instead. Please use Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.
```

even if I try go to the project properties I am getting the same error and I cannot open it.

Second: I found different version on the project [HERE](https://github.com/kedzie/tree-view-list-android) but there is no documentation at all.

I was wondering if there is another approach to complete the task. I checked that I can accomplish it using so called `ExpandableListView` but they can handle only up to two levels and I want more.

Any suggestions???

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: did you try specifically what it says? Right click the project in your package explorer go down to the bottom to Android Tools and inside of the menu that pops out choose Fix Project Properties.

Comment: Yes and i am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented it with Custom ListView, here's a link where I've posted example of my implementation:

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20518117/2219052

Hope it helps.